# Write an update query only if a column exists in a mysql table through a bash script file

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a bash script .sh file in which I am accessing a MySQL database that contains a table called "Foo". I am having trouble with the MySQL syntax to perform an update query to set the value in column "Bar" only if "Bar" exists in table "Foo" and else, update values in other columns in "Foo" without column "Bar". The if/else statement is fed through a wrapper that accesses MySQL command line interface and the update query itself I already have.

I would like to avoid creating a procedure or a function if possible.

Right now, the if/else looks like this:

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Foo' AND 
   column_name='Bar') THEN
       //UPDATE Foo SET Bar query
   ELSE
      //UPDATE Foo without column Bar
   END IF;
```

I have been searching for hours but still am running into a Query Error of:

```
Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Foo' AN' at line 1
```

Comment: You can only use `IF` statements in stored procedures, not ordinary queries.

Comment: Why does the schema of the table change? Something is wrong with your design if you need this conditional.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to avoid a stored procedure, is it the only way to make the logic work?

Comment: If you don't want to do this in a stored procedure, you'll need to perform the query from the script and do the conditional there.

Comment: The schema changes due to multiple versions of the db. This script runs for an older and newer version of the application where the older version does not contain the newly introduced columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the query in the script itself.

```
cols=$(mysql -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME='Foo' AND column_name='Bar'")
if [[ $cols -eq 1 ]]
then
    # perform update with column Bar
else
    # perform update without column Bar
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this in a couple of steps in the bash script.  First do something like:

```
# Create and populate a variable named exists
exists=$(mysql -e "Select 0 from information_schema.columns where...")

# Check to see if $exists is empty/null in bash.

# Do the appropriate update query based on the if statement.
```